# What is the minimum team-size for mission control?

Tags: law, mission-control

There happen to be several questions out here on DIY spacecraft/launch-systems ... so I figure this question should be the next that comes to mind

Unless one happens to be on the craft, and well-trained in handling spacecraft at the extremely large velocities a launch vehicle may attain - there may be a ramp-up curve, or un-manned launch. Regardless such probably require specialized education, and processing power (firm-ware & wet-ware, both).

Assuming it becomes possible for a person to put together a spacecraft on their own,

- Can a person **control** an unmanned spacecraft on their own?
- Is a single person on ground in communication with a manned spacecraft enough?
- What is the minimum team size required to control an unmanned spacecraft from launch through orbit? What about a manned spacecraft?
- Are there any regulations either from [NAR](http://www.nar.org/), or [NASA](http://www.nasa.gov) that define a lower-limit & profiles for mission control of any rocket/space launch?

Comment: @DeerHunter You bring up a good point about the vagueness of Everyone's bolded "control" constraint. There is room for clarification of what he means by "control". An ICBM is controlled to a degree, but is this what Everyone is looking for?

Comment: I think there's at least a few questions here that could be standalone and easier to answer as such. The way it's framed is simply too broad (from rocketry to manned missions).

Comment: Control as in all the factors that go into evaluation of necessary spacecraft components/systems from pre-launch through culmination. E.g. Stage separation, attitude, burn control